# Accessing Ember Controller Properties within the same controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm very new to EmberJS 2.0 and trying to slowly understand it by building my own website with it. Anyways, I've managed to get Firebase integrated with Ember and my controller is able to authenticate correctly. However, I'd like to understand why when I execute:

```
this.send('toggleModal');
```

inside the authenticate action property function (.then()) it doesn't work but if I execute it outside then everything works fine.

1) Is the 'this' keyword getting confused with something other than the Ember controller?

Here is the sample:

```
// /app/controllers/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isShowingModal: false,
  actions: {
    toggleModal: function() {
      this.toggleProperty('isShowingModal');
    },
    authenticate: function(username, pass) {
      this.get('session').open('firebase', {
        provider: "password",
        email: username,
        password: pass
      }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.currentUser);
        console.log(session.isAuthenticated); //Why is 'session' not defined?
        this.send('toggleModal'); //This doesn't work. Throws an error.
      });

      this.send('toggleModal'); //This works.
    },
    logOut: function() {
      this.get('session').close();
    }
  }
});
```

2) Also, I've noticed that when using Emberfire I'm able to use the property 'session.isAuthenticated' within the template application.hbs however, shouldn't 'session' be an object that is injected to all routes and controllers using Torii? Why is that property inaccessible/undefined within the application.js controller? I'm using https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ember/guide.html#section-authentication as a reference.

3) In the guide above the actions for authentication are put inside the route. However, according to this quora post the route should only handle template rendering and model interfacing. Is this post incorrect? The authentication logic should reside in the application.js controller correct? https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-learn-Ember-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Is the 'this' keyword getting confused with something other than the Ember controller?

Yes. This is one of the most common sticking points of Javascript. There's a lot of articles out there about it, but [this one](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/) looked pretty good. To solve it you'll either need to use an arrow function, bind the function to the current context, or save the context in a local variable. (Read that article first though.)

> 2) Also, I've noticed that when using Emberfire I'm able to use the property 'session.isAuthenticated' within the template application.hbs however, shouldn't 'session' be an object that is injected to all routes and controllers using Torii? Why is that property inaccessible/undefined within the application.js controller? ...

That's because the template pulls the property from the current context (your controller). Inside of your controller you'll have to use `this.get('session')` instead. (After you fix the issue I mentioned above.)

> 3) ... Is this post incorrect? ...

I wouldn't say incorrect, just a bit oversimplified. I would follow whatever conventions the library uses as that's probably the best way given the library's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You're partially right about `this` although it's not really confused. `this` (where you're modal call doesn't work) isn't scoped to the Controller anymore, because it's inside a function. Either:

1. replace the `function (data)`  call with `data =>` if you're using ember cli. Or
2. var `_self = this;` up top and reference `_self` instead.

This should at least get you started.

Comment: also, you should just `let session = this.get('session');` at the top and refer to `session` later, that will address your `undefined` (because you never defined it).